# Filemaker XML Import via Script, no Order Possible?

Tags: xml, filemaker

i want to do a probably very simple thing. When entering a record i want to import XML via a script with a Calculation like this:

```
"https://www.WEBSITE.com/test.php?id=" & MyTable::ID
```

When entering the record it should import the link as stated above and then automatically update the according record by the ID. Problem is that i can not predefine the Import order because the XML is based on what id is added to the line. ERGO it would be empty without an ID.

When i manually use import XML Data to update a record it works so my XML works fine.

Has anybody faced the same problem and come to a solution?

Thanks in advance i've found so much help here in the past

Comment: The context of your question is not quite clear. Can you elaborate on how you do this manually?

Comment: Well i use the Import Feature from the menu. Then type my URL and add an ID that i know exists. But i would want my Script to get that by itself :)

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you try to script this and you enter your formula into the 'Specify XML Data Source -> Calculation' dialog box (within the Import Records[] script step)?

Comment: I can not run this in the background because i can not predefine which is the comparing field and which fields to import where. And i don't want the user to always have to do that

Comment: Sorry, you have lost me at this point. I thought you asked how to script something you do manually. I suggest you edit your question ansd explain what you need, **in much more detail.**

Comment: is it now detailed enough? I really tried most things and googled around and used the Missing Manual...but i have not found a solution to my Problem :/

Comment: No, I am afraid it's not.

Comment: Whats missing to understand it? :/

Comment: I don't know. I will tell you **after** I understand it - if that ever happens. How about posting the resulting XML, explaining how it may differ as a result of a different id (if there are different versions, post examples of them), a list of your target fields and an explanation of how you want to map the XML response/s to your fields. If you use an XSLT stylesheet, include that too. That should provide a start.

Comment: One more thing: if you cannot "predefine which fields to import where" (or at least expound the logic of which fields should go where), then there is no way you'll be able to script this.

Comment: Thanks for trying...but i just found the solution -.- The import order has to exactly match the Order in which the XML outputs it...i did not know this. Thanks for trying to understand me :)

Comment: That's not exactly true: the fields can be *mapped*, either manually or by matching names, and the mapping  will be stored in the script step. Anyway, I am glad to hear you found a solution.

Comment: Hey @TP3 you could also parse the xml data using the xpath function in the baseelements plugin. With that you could set each of the fields regardless of the order in the xml: http://www.goya.com.au/baseelements/plugin